# Chrome extension "executeScript" not works with mac

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I developed a google chrome extension that works good with Windows OS. but the problem that does not work with mac, I tried to check the problem, I found that function

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript
```

does not work on mac, this is the completely code that worked good with windows not mac.

```
// The onClicked callback function.
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
                // the problem in injecting code
                chrome.tabs.executeScript
               ( null,{code:"var activeElm = document.activeElement; var inp_text = activeElm.value; console.log(activeElm.value);"});
};

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);

// Set up context menu tree at install time.
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  // Intentionally create an invalid item, to show off error checking in the
  // create callback.
  console.log("About to try creating an invalid item - an error about " +
      "duplicate item child1 should show up");
  chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "consoleMe", "id": "child523", "contexts":["selection"]}, function() {
    if (chrome.extension.lastError) {
      console.log("Got expected error: " + chrome.extension.lastError.message);
    }
  });
});
```

**Hint**:

I use **content_scripts** injection files in the manifest file, but it seems did not activated on Google chrome on Mac.

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "js" : ["jquery.min.js","fix.js","injscript.js"],
      "all_frames": false
    }
  ],
```

OS : Mac 10.8 Mountain lion -- 
Google Chrome V 32

Answer (score 1):

There should be no difference between Windows and Mac. It's likely that something else is different between your two setups.

It's not clear to me whether the javascript snippet above is a background script or an injected content script. Can you provide the full manifest and indicate which file the snippet belongs to?

- If it's a background script, chrome.tabs.executeScript with null tabId will apply to the background page, which is not what you expect. Instead, pass tab.id for the tabId.
- If it's a content script, the contextMenus API calls won't work because content scripts are not allowed to use chrome APIs (see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html).